# How to resolve GetUserCallback?

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 * Created by Software Engineer on 7/14/2016.
 */
public class ServerRequests {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://manibala.comlu.com/";

    public ServerRequests(Context context) {
        // Instantiate Progress Dialogue
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        // Set the attribute of Progress Dialogue
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallBack callBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `k` tagged?

Answer (score 0):

Create interface in Java package. ex: make file called GetUserCallback.java

```
interface GetUserCallback {
    public abstract void done(User returnedUser);
}
```

That's it done!